# I want it automatically moving infinity time grid horizontally image attached

Tags: flutter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CIUbY.png)I have to achieve moving automatically staggered grid view with have different size of circuleravter of each index and moving until app is killed.

I want it automatically moving infinity time .

£flutter ,flutters,flutter moving stiggred grid

Comment: Write some custom code to implement it. I don't think you can find an existing solution. I would personally come up with some patterns of the grid view and then repeat them. For auto scrolling I would repeatedly change an offset inside a timer